# Segmentation fault caused by deleting pointer that should be null

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have written a custom string and vector classes. Occasionally (but consistently) when adding the string to the vector, the program tries to delete the char pointer (which should be null), causing a seg fault. Even going step by step through the debugger, I cannot figure out how this pointer is not a nullptr as it normally is.

Here are my three constructors for my string class, as well as the = overload which is where the segfault is occurring. Note, I do have a simple destructor that deletes both data and tempreturn if they are not null.

```
//default constructor
AString::AString(){
    this->length = 0;
    this->cap = 0;
    this->data = nullptr;
    this->tempReturn = nullptr;
}

//constructor with arguments for char*
AString::AString(const char* newData){
    this->length = strlen(newData);
    this->cap = this->length + 1;
    this->data = new char[this->cap];
    this->tempReturn = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->length; i ++){
        this->data[i] = newData[i];
    }
    this->data[length] ='\0';
}

//constructor with arguments for passing a string by reference
AString::AString(const AString& newData){
    this->length = newData.length;
    this->cap = this->length + 1;
    this->data = new char[this->cap];
    this->tempReturn = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->length; i++){
        this->data[i] = newData.data[i];
    } 
    this->data[length] ='\0';
}

//called with the = string reference
AString& AString::operator= (const AString& newData){
    if(data != nullptr){
        delete[] data;    //This is where it seg faults.
    }

    this->length = newData.length;
    this->cap = newData.length + 1;
    this->data = new char[this->cap];
    for(int i = 0; i < this->length; i ++){
        data[i] = newData.data[i];
    }
    this->data[length] ='\0';

    return *this;
}
```

At that line, data should be a nullptr and length should be zero. However, at the same element each time, data is filled with a location that holds no chars and length is 33. tempreturn, which should also be null, appears to be holding nonsensical chars

Also for reference, my vector constructor and pushback method that leads into the seg fault

```
  //default constructor setting number of elements to empty, and give a 
  //default capacity and initialize array;
 template <class T>
 AVector<T>::AVector(){
     this->cap = 10;
     this->numElements = 0;
     this->data = new T[cap];
 }
 template <class T>
 void AVector<T>::pushBack(T type){
     //add it to the end of the current index
     this->data[numElements] = type;    //line that leads into the segfault
     //increase the tracker for how many elements added
     numElements++;
     //if new element exceeds previously established array
     if(numElements >= cap) {
         increaseCapacity(this->cap * 2);
     }

 }
```

Comment: Unrelated: you don't need a test like `if(data != nullptr)` before you `delete`. One of the first things `delete` does is test for null.

Comment: You're right, I was somehow blind when reading your question.  The self-assignment check should be `if(this != &newData)`.

Comment: Can you add the function used to remove elements from `AVector`?  I suspect that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Need a [mcve] to sort this out, I think. Nothing jumps out in `AString`, but there is tonnes of room in `AVector` that isn't shown that can set up a damaged/non-existent `AString`.

Comment: Stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: Does it crash after the 10th pushback by anychance? Can you put the increaseCapacity() code please.